# Reset index error when I run the following code

Tags: python, pandas

```py
df_rate_type_abc=df_rate_type.groupby(['AB10_RANGE', 'AB10_RANGING'], as_index =False).apply(lambda x: sorted(x['rate_type'].unique())).reset_index(name='rate_types')
```

Comment: What do you want to do and what's the error? As far as I know, there is no `name` argument in [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Answer (score 0):

For use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) need specify column `rate_type` after `groupby` for `Series`:

```
df_rate_type_abc=(df_rate_type.groupby(['AB10_RANGE', 'AB10_RANGING'])['rate_type']
                              .apply(lambda x: sorted(x.unique()))
                              .reset_index(name='rate_types'))
```

Another idea is use:

```
df_rate_type_abc=(df_rate_type.sort_values(['AB10_RANGE','AB10_RANGING','rate_type'])
                              .groupby(['AB10_RANGE', 'AB10_RANGING'])['rate_type']
                              .unique()
                              .reset_index(name='rate_types'))
```